# How to provide a basic authentication for Kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, proxy, basic-authentication, haproxy

I am running a quite easy setup for ES+Kibana. I have the following 2 AWS instances as follows:

HAProxy Instance & ES+Kibana Instance (both on same machine) The whole set-up is straight foreword, HAProxy redirects request to Kibana Dashboard. The Haproxy holds my certificate is not a dedicated instance i.e it is also responsible to send connections to other monitoring instances that i own.

So It looks like :

```
                                      |---->> Monitor 1
  Request ------------> HAPROXY ------|---->> Monitor 2
                                      |---->> (Kibana+ES_server)
```

I need a basic authentication for Kibana+ES_Server only, which basically should ask a User its username & password after it hit the URL.

P.S I am also using Browser based certificates. What should be my approach? I am expecting a number of ways here and the best approach to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Elasticsearch basic authentication plugin - 
[click here for elasticsearch](https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic)

for kibana try kibana-authentication-proxy

[click here for kibana](https://github.com/fangli/kibana-authentication-proxy)